# ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected

Tags: python

```
input =Input(shape=(None,inputX[0].shape[1]))

x1 = layers.Bidirectional(LSTM(100,return_sequences=True),merge_mode='sum')(input)

x2 = layers.Bidirectional(LSTM(100,return_sequences=True),merge_mode='sum')(x1)

x3 = layers.Bidirectional(LSTM(100,return_sequences=True),merge_mode='sum')(x2)
x4 = layers.Bidirectional(LSTM(3,return_sequences=True),merge_mode='sum')(x3)

output=Activation('softmax')(x4)

model=Model(input,output)
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=10)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])



fitHistory_batch = model.fit(trainX,trainY, batch_size=1000, validation_data=([valX,valX],valY),epochs=100,callbacks=[early_stopping])
```

The trainX is a list of arrays, for example,

```
trainX[0].shape = 192 * 151
trainX[1].shape  = 256 * 151
```

The trainY is a list of arrays, for example,

```
trainY[0].shape = 192 * 3
trainY[1].shape = 256 * 3
```

`valX` and `valY` are like `trainX` and `trainY` respectively.

I am getting this error,

```
ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected.
```

Answer (score 0):

The shape of the input layer is not the same as the training data, that is why you are getting the error.
Use this as the input layer instead,

```
input = Input(shape=trainX[0].shape)
```